# Centering text/div for menu navigation

Tags: html, css, menubar, navigationbar, bigcommerce

Firstly -- Here's a [link](http://timepiecetheatre.com/) to my site where you can see the problem with the main navigation being more aligned to the left. I'm hoping to have the elements centered in the white space of the header.

Here's the code being used.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="HeaderLower">
                <div class="Block" >
                    <div class="Block Panel BlockContent" id="Menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="First %%GLOBAL_ActivePageHomeClass%%"><a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPathNormal%%/"><span>%%LNG_MainPage%%</span></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

</div>
                %%Panel.SideCategoryList%%
                %%Panel.PagesMenu%%
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#HeaderLower .Block {
float: left;
margin: 0 !important;
}


#HeaderLower ul{

list-style-type: none;
float: none !important;
width: auto !important;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#HeaderLower li {


float: left !important;
width: auto !important;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
margin: -3px 0 0 0;
padding: 0 40px 0 0;
}


#HeaderLower {
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 980px;
min-height: 50px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
```

I'm using Bigcommerce, and their code files are a hodgepodge, so I apologize for length. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Your posted code as-is does not do a very good job at explaining what the issue is (also, there's an extra stray `</div>` at the end), here's a live demo of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/dZ75d/ what's wrong with this, and what did you expect instead? Start with adding some colors or borders so we can see what's what and remove any unnecessary code.

Comment: @xec You fiddle doesn't show anything. timepiecetheatre : You nav is perfectly centered, what do want ?

Comment: I am using Bigcommerce, so it's an incredibly tricky system, with pages and pages of code. I'm certainly not a code expert, clearly. I tried to post the code I thought was relevant, without posting too much or too little.

The result you're seeing is based on Bigcommerce's system of referencing webpages that you create in their website builder program.

Comment: @singe31 The link does work for me, although I agree that the output window doesn't show much of value, which was my point :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do one thing that

```
#HeaderLower li {


float: left !important;
width: auto !important;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
margin: -3px 0 0 0;
padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Try this it will work for you If not tell me I'll update code

Another way you can use below Jquery I'll dynamically handle your left and right padding

you can update code this is not updated as per your code, apply "horizontally-align" class on UL

```
$('.horizontally-align').each(function () {
    var ul = $(this);
    var ulWidth = ul.width();

    var links = ul.find('> li > a');
    var texts = links.find('> span.text');

    var numOfLinks = links.length;
    // set the width of all A tags to the width of the UL divided by the number of A tags
    // using Math.floor to round down to the nearest whole number
    var linkBaseWidth = Math.floor(ulWidth / numOfLinks);
    links.each(function () {
        var a = $(this);
        var li = a.parent();
        var text = a.find('span.text');
        //var borderWidth = a.find('span.border').width();

        a.outerWidth(linkBaseWidth);

        if (li.hasClass('first') || li.hasClass('last')) {
            var textWidth = a.outerWidth();

            //extra calculations for first and last elements of the UL because of sidecap use to support defunct browsers.
            if (li.hasClass('first')) {
               a.width(linkBaseWidth);

                a.css('padding-right', padding);

            } else { // must be class 'last'

            }
        }
        a.css('width', linkBaseWidth);
    });

    // the difference between the width of the UL and the combined width of all A tags
    var widthDifference = ulWidth - (Math.floor(ulWidth / numOfLinks) * numOfLinks);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
#HeaderLower .Block {
  float: left;margin: 0 !important;
}
```

to this

```
#HeaderLower .Block {
  margin: 0 auto;width: 885px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you 4dgaurav, didnt notice that horribe size :(

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have *a lot* of weird/unecessary css code here. You can disable most of them using a DOM inspector and the rendering does not change at all. I have boiled down your posted code a bit (and added colors for visualization) at http://jsfiddle.net/t24J6/ and if I understand your question correctly, you want the inline menu elements to be centered.

One way to do this is to simply set `text-align: center;` on the containing element and the rest should be fine - here's an example derived from your posted code:

```css
#HeaderLower {
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
#HeaderLower ul{
    text-align: center; /* center the menu items */
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#HeaderLower li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
#HeaderLower li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t24J6/1/

Comment: I had tried a lot of the basic css implementations like text alignment, and adjusting margins, unfortunately  none have worked. Bigcommerce is a bit strange, and I'm noticing simple things like aligning menu text turns into a huge project of trial and error. 

Thanks for your response. I wish I knew what code to post that might be more relevant to the situation I'm in. But again -- Thank you for your help.

Comment: @timepiecetheatre FWIW I tested this method of centering on your live page and it works just fine.

Comment: I have it in the code now, and I've checked it from two separate computers on Google Chrome and Firefox. I can't imagine why it's not working.

Comment: @timepiecetheatre I can't see it when inspecting the live page at the moment, if that's what you're talking about?

Comment: Could you post what you see when you go to the site, perhaps? Here is what I'm seeing now:
http://i.imgur.com/gbiVFug.png

I reverted the code back to the original I had, except with the text alignment you suggested, but this is what I see. 

Thank you for your patience with me ._. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @timepiecetheatre This is what I see: http://imgur.com/tJxcEDZ - Note that I have removed `float: left` (both from the `<li>` and the parent) and added `display: inline-block;` to the `<li>`